# Decide shape with neural network in PHP

Tags: php

So, I found this class online, which is a neural network programmed in PHP. You can find it here: http://pastebin.com/vVn4CABh

However, I want it to perform an action based on the input. The input will be a 3*3 grid filled with black or white squares. The square create an 'H' or a 'T'. So, I created some PHP code for this. But I'm struggling with it.

In the code below, I made one square of a T-shape black, but it still thinks it's a T.

```
$n = new NeuralNetwork(3, 4, 1);
$n->setVerbose(false);

//shape of T and H in 3*3 grid
$n->addTestData(array(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), array (0));
$n->addTestData(array(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), array (1));


$max = 3;


while (!($success = $n->train(1000, 0.01)) && $max -- > 0) {
    echo "Nothing found...<hr />";
}


if ($success) {
    $epochs = $n->getEpoch();
    echo "Success in $epochs training rounds!<hr />";
}

//T with one black square
$shape = $n->calculate(array(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0));

$shape = $n->calculate(array(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0));

print "output from neural network = (".implode(", ", $shape).")\n";
if ($shape > 0.5) {
    print "The shape is an H.";
} else {
    print "The shape is a T.";
}
```

Comment: Surely you should be using `if ($shape == 1) { print "The shape is an H.";`? as you've assigned `1` to your `H` mapping?

Comment: Oh, right, I added it, but the output is `The shape is an H.`. So there must still be something wrong...

Comment: So what is the value of $shape?